# Stream Analytics job has validation errors: Job will exceed the maximum amount of Event Hub Receivers.

Tags: azure, iot, unpivot, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to write a query in ASA (Azure Stream Analytics) where the input is a json line message that looks like this

```
{
    "DeviceId": "Device3",
    "DateTime": "2016-09-05T13:23:04.5444423",
    "Value": [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 ]
}
```

And what I want to do is to perform an Unpivot so the data comes on the form

```
create table LightBeacon (
     DeviceId int primary key not null,
     EventDateTime datetime not null,
     LightBeaconId varchar(25) not null,
     LightBeaconState SmallInt not null
)
```

But seems that ASA do not support the SQL Unpivot function and is there by left with multi select statements like

```
with 
    DataUnArray as (    
        SELECT DeviceId, DateTime as EventDateTime
            , GetArrayElement(Value, 0) as LigthBeacon01
            , GetArrayElement(Value, 1) as LigthBeacon02
            , GetArrayElement(Value, 2) as LigthBeacon03
            , GetArrayElement(Value, 3) as LigthBeacon04
            , GetArrayElement(Value, 4) as LigthBeacon05
            , GetArrayElement(Value, 5) as LigthBeacon06
            , GetArrayElement(Value, 6) as LigthBeacon07
        FROM DataIoT
        where DeviceId = 'Device3'),
    DataUnpivot as (
            select DeviceId, EventDateTime, 'LigthBeacon01' as LigthBeaconId, LigthBeacon01 as LigthBeaconState from DataUnArray
        Union All select DeviceId, EventDateTime, 'LigthBeacon02' as LigthBeaconId, LigthBeacon02 as LigthBeaconState from DataUnArray
        Union All select DeviceId, EventDateTime, 'LigthBeacon03' as LigthBeaconId, LigthBeacon03 as LigthBeaconState from DataUnArray
        Union All select DeviceId, EventDateTime, 'LigthBeacon04' as LigthBeaconId, LigthBeacon04 as LigthBeaconState from DataUnArray
        Union All select DeviceId, EventDateTime, 'LigthBeacon05' as LigthBeaconId, LigthBeacon05 as LigthBeaconState from DataUnArray
        Union All select DeviceId, EventDateTime, 'LigthBeacon06' as LigthBeaconId, LigthBeacon06 as LigthBeaconState from DataUnArray
        Union All select DeviceId, EventDateTime, 'LigthBeacon07' as LigthBeaconId, LigthBeacon07 as LigthBeaconState from DataUnArray
    )   
    select DeviceId, EventDateTime, LigthBeaconId, LigthBeaconState
    into DataLakeCSV
    from DataUnpivot
```

The ASA Query is failing to start with the following error:

> Stream Analytics job has validation errors: Job will exceed the
>   maximum amount of Event Hub Receivers

If I reduce it to 5 beacon – it works!!! So how can I write a ASA Query that can handle more than 5 columns in an unpivot?

\Bjørn

Answer (score 1):

UNPIVOT is unsupported, but you can achieve the same results with CROSS APPLY and GetRecordProperties function:

```
WITH DataUnArray
AS (
    SELECT DeviceId
        ,DATETIME AS EventDateTime
        ,GetArrayElement(Value, 0) AS LigthBeacon01
        ,GetArrayElement(Value, 1) AS LigthBeacon02
        ,GetArrayElement(Value, 2) AS LigthBeacon03
        ,GetArrayElement(Value, 3) AS LigthBeacon04
        ,GetArrayElement(Value, 4) AS LigthBeacon05
        ,GetArrayElement(Value, 5) AS LigthBeacon06
        ,GetArrayElement(Value, 6) AS LigthBeacon07
    FROM DataIoT
    WHERE DeviceId = 'Device3'
    )

SELECT    
     event.DeviceId
    ,event.EventDateTime
    ,p.PropertyName AS LigthBeaconId,
     p.PropertyValue AS LigthBeaconState
 FROM DataUnArray event
 CROSS APPLY GetRecordProperties(event) p
 WHERE p.PropertyName LIKE 'ligthbeacon%'
```

Comment: It Works - perfect. 
I did a rewrite of the code using GetArrayElements - which made it simple and even more powerfull.